# Copy file giving a similar name

Tags: c#

Let's say there is a file: `"C:\work\foo.txt"`.

I know I can use this method: `System.IO.File.Copy(oldPathAndName, newPathAndName);`, but I do want the new created file to have a name similar as the initial file, something like this: `foo(1).txt`.

I have the possibility to create as many files as I want => `foo(2).txt`, `foo(3).txt`, and so on...

Currently, I am giving a random file name, using `Guid.NewGuid().ToString()`

Comment: Do you want to copy that file into the same folder?

Comment: Yes, sorry, forgot to mention

Comment: You could use the result of `Directory.EnumerateFiles(folderName).Count(f => f.Contains(fileName))` to insert into new file name.

Answer (score 0):

Use the [Path class](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.path%28v=vs.110%29.aspx). Something like:

```
int YourNumber = 1;

    String newFilename = GetFileNameWithoutExtension(oldName) + YourNumber++ + GetExtension(oldName);
```

Comment: What will become if we restart program?

Comment: good point... you have to check if the file exists as Chaka does. :-)